# arcanist editor exception in git-bash on windows

Tags: git-bash, arcanist

Has anyone ever seen behavior like this:

```
<<< [34] <exec> 139,398 us
>>> [35] <exec> $ vim  "C:\Users\JMORDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\edit.aannm9clj1kosok4\new-commit"
<<< [35] <exec> 1,489 us
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Editor exited with an error code (#1).' in C:\arcanist\ph-arcWindows-u0001\libphutil\src\console\PhutilInteractiveEditor.php:94
```

It looks like it's trying to open a file in the Windows temp directory but gitbash vim seems to not understand the path. Trying to run that command from the prompt fails to open the file in question. I'm brand new to arcanist and a google search didn't turn anything up. Anyone have any ideas of what I can do here?

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? I came across the same problem.

Comment: Nope. Gave up on windows. Set it up on a linux vm :/

Comment: It is MacOS, and I have it done.  Added 'filetype on' into my vimrc, it worked, but I do not know why.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS X, there seems to be a bug with vim. I fixed this issue by following https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15848.

> Do you have filetype off in your vimrc? Try replacing it with:
>
> ```
> filetype on
> filetype off
> ```
>
> I had this problem using Tim Pope's Pathogen on OS X. This article
>   helped me solve the issue. If you are using Pathogen...
>
> call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles() ...do this instead:
>
> ```
> filetype on
> filetype off
> call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
> call pathogen#helptags()
> filetype plugin indent on
> ```
>
> http://andrewho.co.uk/weblog/vim-pathogen-with-mutt-and-git